# join attributes from lines to points that overlaps in r

Tags: r, join, spatial, point, multiline

I have `linestrings` which have attibutes and I want to create `points` from it but keeping the linestring's attributes. I've tried with `st_cast("POINT")` which keep the attributes information from lines to points, but the resultant points are very separated. I've also tried with `st_line_sample` which I like because resultant points are more regular, but doesn't keep attributes information from lines to points.
I'm looking a way to join the attributes information from lines to points that overlaps.

I have the next reproducible example (here the attribute is the `info` column).

```
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(mapview)
crs_utm<- 32719

# MULTILINESTRING with column info as attribute
ChileMap <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(scale = "small", country = "chile", returnclass = "sf")[1] %>% 
    st_cast("MULTILINESTRING") %>% st_transform(crs_utm) %>% mutate(info = "info")

mapview(ChileMap)

# I create points with st_cast and keep attributes from linestring but these are so separated
ChilePoint_stcast<- ChileMap %>% st_cast("POINT")
mapview(ChilePoint_stcast)

# I use st_line_sample but it does not keep the attributes information :( 
ChilePoint_stsample<- ChileMap %>% 
   st_cast("LINESTRING") %>% 
   st_line_sample(density = 1/10000) %>% 
   st_cast("POINT")
mapview(ChilePoint_stsample)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it with `st_intersection` and making a to the linestring, because `st_line_sample` does not always intersect the points with the linestring.
So,

```
chile_buffer<- st_buffer(ChileMap, dist = 4)

output<- st_intersection(chile_buffer, ChilePoint_stsample) %>% 
  st_difference()
```